# axios react get real-time data display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, axios, fetch

I  made an Axios get request to get data  to display it with react

```
export function Wareh() {
  const [wareh, setWareh] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:1515/wareh").then((response) => {
      setWareh((existingData) => {
        return response.data;
      });
    });
  }, []);
  return wareh;
}
```

the problem here if i update my data i have to refresh the page to see the udpate Here is my question :

how to make itto be like r like if any changes happens in the database it reflects the get request.

Comment: Two possibilities here: 1. polling (timed requests e.g. every 5s which get the current data) 2. some kind of server -> client communication (e.g. based on web sockets. So all clients subscribe to a specific socket event and whenever a change is made, the server notifies all subscribed clients via broadcast about the changes). The second possibility is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to achieve this. Either you can do it using

1. Long pooling

In this technique, you can set Interval and call the same endpoint to refresh the data with the passage of time.

```
setInterval(() => fetchWareh(), 5000)
```

Let's assume you can shift your Axios call to a function named: fetchWareh and call the same function after every 5 seconds

2. Server Sent Event
   This is approach is quite similar to the first approach. You read more about from here:

[https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react-hooks)

3. Implement socket on server & client

A most recommended to do it through socket.io to fetch real-time data.

[Socket Documentation Here](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react-hooks)

Comment: Yeah, as he told i think you try to use third way direct because the way is correct most of time.